I was wondering how to run scheduled jobs in the foreground instead of in the background
I was wondering how to run scheduled jobs as a foreground task instead of in the background.
Similar to the logontype in scheduled task. How do you use scheduled and implement these features?
The scheduled job runs in the background by default, but I want it to run it in the foreground. I want it to be visible to me while it runs.
$jo = New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated
$jt = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn
Register-ScheduledJob -Name 'get_command' -scriptblock {get-command} -ScheduledJobOption $jo -Trigger $jt

The code above runs in the background. I want it to run in the foreground.
Is there a way to do this?

See the duplicate at ServerFault:  How can I invoke a foreground process from a background PowerShell Job?

@iRon I can do foreground work on schtasks enough, but I was just looking for another way available on scheduledjob. Because scheduledjob is very convenient.
